# FCM does not send webpush notifications

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM for sending notifications, it works perfectly with notification and data, but when I try to send a webpush object, it ignores it.

This is the request example that I am using.

```
{
  "message":{
     "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
     "notification":{
       "title":"Match update",
       "body":"Arsenal goal in added time, score is now 3-0"
     },
     "data": {
       "key1": "value"
     }
     "webpush":{
       "notification":{
         "click_action":"something"
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Do you have any server logs or anything indicating what messages it "sees"?

Comment: {data: {…}, from: "839433111111", notification: {…}, collapse_key: "do_not_collapse"}collapse_key: "do_not_collapse"data: {phone_number: "111111111", crm_status: "new", id: "30888441"}from: "839433628399"notification: {title: "New One", body: "You have a new costumer", click_action: "NOTIFICATION_ACTION_NEW"}proto: Object

Comment: Put the code or errors in the post not in comments please